# How do I append new HttpCookie in existing map of request cookies?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

We have recently migrated to Spring Cloud Gateway from Netflix Zuul framework.
We are facing a basic issue related to appending new HttpCookie in the existing map of request cookies.
While investigating the code we found that the getCookies API of AbstractServerHttpRequest class(spring-web project) provides an unmodifiable map of cookies as follows:

```
    @Override
    public MultiValueMap<String, HttpCookie> getCookies() {
        if (this.cookies == null) {
            this.cookies = CollectionUtils.unmodifiableMultiValueMap(initCookies());
        }
        return this.cookies;
    }
```

We tried to modify the cookie map by retrieving the Decorator of SeverHttpRequest object using mutate API as follows however it did not work.

```
   final ServerHttpRequest mutatedRequest = exchange.getRequest().mutate().build();
   mutatedRequest.getCookies().add("sessionid", new HttpCookie("sessionid", "abcdedf"));
```

Instead we encountered `UnsupportedOperationException` with above change.

The appending of new cookies in existing request cookies was quite possible in Spring MVC framework, however it seems to be a challenge in Spring Webflux framework.

Could you please provide all possible solution or code snippet to achieve this basic requirement?